# Show and Close form from a background thread

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a windows form (AlertForm) that displays a progress bar. I am trying to show it an close it thru a task. The problem that I am having is when I spawn a thread and call winforms.showdialog() it holds the thread and therefore cant cancel it. I am doing this because I am writing an excel add in thru c# in which I don't have a panel to show a progress bar.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AlertForm alert = new AlertForm();
        var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken ct = ts.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //while (true)
            //{
                // do some heavy work here
                alert.ShowDialog();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    alert.Close();
                    // another thread decided to cancel
                    Console.WriteLine("task canceled");
                    //break;
                }
            //}
        }, ct);

        // Simulate waiting 3s for the task to complete
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // Can't wait anymore => cancel this task 
        ts.Cancel();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

How do I open the form and not hold it so at a later stage when a long task is complete I can cancel the task which will close the window
 (AlertForm)?

Answer (score -2):

If the AlertForm class is inheritance from Windows.Forms.Control then you can use Invoke method

```cs
alert.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () 
{
    alert.Close();
});
```

Comment: it doesn't its a regular winforms but while this windows is up and running eventually I need to close once its done by cancel?